# Any reviews on IRCAM SPAT plugin?

Tags: plugin, review, design, post-production

Hey everyone.  I was wondering if anybody has used the IRCAM SPAT plugin.  I saw a demo of it at AES this year and it seemed pretty nice.

Comment: I would like to know too. I was at AES, didn't know Flux was there. I certainly would've checked it out. Care to elaborate on what you liked about it...

Comment: Flux was at an afterparty doing demos.  It was a 3D Spatial Simulator that did a good job at simulating the space of a 360 degree radius on only 2 speakers.  There was a height, depth, and width setting along with some other things.  Overall, I was drooling over it until I found out how much it cost the next day.  